# Get input duration on Phaser js 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to get the pointer duration when I click on a sprite with Phaser 3.

```
sprite.setInteractive();
sprite.on('pointerup', function (pointer) {
      console.log(pointer.duration);
});
```

The above code prints always "undefined"

any help?

Comment: OK I found it! I use Phaser 3.15.1, there is not duration attribute but there is upTime and downTime attributes. So, I can calculate it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To measure the duration of a touch event on your sprite try this:

```
console.log(pointer.upTime-pointer.downTime);
```

In the function

```
sprite.on('pointerup', function (pointer) {
    console.log(pointer.upTime-pointer.downTime);
});
```

`downTime` is the internal timestamp for the time when touch was pressed, `upTime` for release.

Comment: Dash sign in method name, really?!

Comment: @Vadim it's a minus sign, I should have added a whitespace